# How to disable moveit octomap

Tags: moveit, octomap, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

When i launch `move_group.launch` as generated by the moveit setup assistant I get the error that no sensor plugin is specified for the octomap updater. How can I disable the octomap updater entirely? Because I dont have any sensor and am not interested in using the octomap at all.

```
Starting context monitors... 
[ INFO] [1540472290.226138098]: Starting scene monitor
[ INFO] [1540472290.227961352]: Listening to '/planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1540472290.227977222]: Starting world geometry monitor
[ INFO] [1540472290.229877757]: Listening to '/collision_object' using message notifier with target frame '/world '
[ INFO] [1540472290.232777616, 482.172000000]: Listening to '/planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[ERROR] [1540472290.233755215, 482.173000000]: No sensor plugin specified for octomap updater 0; ignoring.
[ INFO] [1540472290.258212975, 482.197000000]: Listening to '/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
Context monitors started.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306733/how-to-disable-moveit-octomap/) by [maxbaeten](https://answers.ros.org/users/15146/maxbaeten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can safely ignore that, it doesn't influence anything.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-28**:
Issue here: [ros-planning/moveit#1680](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/1680).

**Comment by [leander](https://answers.ros.org/users/110061/leander/) on 2023-07-06**:
If it can be safely ignored, it shouldn't have ERROR severity.

In fact, there should be a way to completely disable this feature, so it doesn't spam the terminal with unwanted messages that make debugging harder.